# Auth through EAP-TLS for non-domain printer

Tags: certificate, tls, radius

I cannot find a proper tutorial on how to solve my problem. Our company uses for authentication EAP-TLS for wireless. Now I plan to implement 802.1X for ethernet wired connections for enhanced security.

Our printer connected via ethernet is having some troubles while authenticating towards NPAS on Windows Server 2016. I have successfully imported private certificate issued by our CA to the printer.

In event viewer on the server I can see the following event: Audit Failure, Reason: The specified user account does not exist.

I have read that the device needs to be part of the domain to authenticate.

Now on the Internet, you can find people mentioning some methods (Radius proxy, dummy user, etc.) but nobody explains it in sufficient details. Providing some basic steps would be useful.

Comment: Do your NPAS logs show what user account specifically the printer is trying to use?

Comment: @grawity The printer is authenticating with name of the printer in format company\nameoftheprinter. Would creating fake user with name of the printer sufficient? I am not sure, thank you for your reply. The thing is, how printer decides to which name use? As with windows computer, our printer has some random identiefier name, and that identiefier which is shorter than the full name of the printer is used as auth name. Do not forget my authentication method is via certificates. Thank you.